# Using QThread in embedded PyQt application

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, qt, pyqt4

I have written a Qt application in c++ which embeds the Python interpreter and makes use of PyQt to allow for scriptable user interfaces for data analysis. The Python code does some computations on the data and returns a QWidget (containing various plots etc.) which gets inserted into the main application.

I would like to spawn a new QThread from Python to allow control to return to the c++ application so that heavy computations do not block the main thread in which the GUI runs. The problem is that as soon as control is returned back to the c++ application, the thread appears to go to sleep until the Python interpreter is somehow invoked again, eg. a mouseover event on a matplotlib plot. I suspect this is somehow due to Python's GIL.

How can I have a QThread created from Python continue to run after control passes back to the embedding application?

I am using the following code to test. The embedding application calls test_thread() and adds the returned container to a QTabwidget. The thread only executes as I generate mouse events over the matplotlib plot.

```
import time

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()  

class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    def do_work(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            print 'worker running'
            time.sleep(1)

        self.finished.emit()


class Controller(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.do_work)
        self.thread.finished.connect(app.exit)

    def start_thread(self):
        self.thread.start()


class Container(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.controller = Controller()
        self.controller.start_thread()

        self.fig = Figure(dpi=72, facecolor=(1, 1, 1), edgecolor=(0, 0, 0))
        self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)


def test_thread():
    container = Container()
    return container
```

Answer (score 0):

CPython is single threaded because of GIL or Global Interpreter Lock. You cannot run more than 1 concurrent thread from python.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Qt is not blocking you here, python is. The only workaround here is to spawn separate python process for your worker "thread" then use IPC (sockets, shared memory, etc) to communicate between processes. Qt provides interfaces for these IPC mechanisms. You will just have to serialize your interprocess communication.

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSharedMemory.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QLocalSocket.html

This assumed you were asking about concurrency. Regarding something else, and editing answer to clarify jurisdiction,

> How can I have a QThread created from Python continue to run after control passes back to the embedding application?

This is 100% up to the embedding application. The python interpreter **must** be allowed to continue to run by the embedding application. If the embedding application does not allow python to continue to run, then any attempts to circumvent this will result in problems.

Comment: I'm new to threading in Python, but my understanding was that I can still spawn multiple threads, the GIL just prevents them from running simultaneously. I can see how this is a limitation for multithreading within Python, but shouldn't I be able to have a Python thread running alongside a QThread on the C++ side? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Threads started from Python with block other python-started threads.

Comment: So the main Python thread is blocking the new thread I'm creating? Is it not possible to release the GIL somehow to allow the other thread to run?

Comment: There are ways to release the GIL from C/C++ extensions. These are done as, http://docs.python.org/release/3.4.0/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code  . If embedding application is calling python, then it is up to the embedding application on how python is executed. You can't really circumvent that by creating threads (even outside python) because the python interpreter has to run to provide the glue between your worker and embedding application.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your case where it seems that python interpreter is started by 3rd party application, that 3rd party application controls python. When control goes back to that app, python lose GIL. It is up to the 3rd party application to enable python to continue to run. You can't circumvent that from within the interpreter.

Comment: The embedding application is not 3rd party, I wrote it myself, so I can change how Python is called if need be. This is along the lines of what I assumed was happening, what I'm really asking is, is there a way to keep Python running after control returns to the embedding application. I'm not trying to circumvent anything from within the Python code. The point of the thread is simply so that C++ doesn't wait for my entire Python code to run before it can resume execution and display the QWidget to the screen. Sorry if that was not clear.